# Cut last 4 digits from mysql column and insert them in another column

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I have a website that reviews movies.

I was inserting the release year of the movie with the movie name

Now I created another column in the table of the movies `movies` which is called `Year`

Now what I want to do is to cut the last 4 digits in all records from the Name column and insert them into `Year` Column

How can I do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lPv0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update and substring

```
update mytable
set year = SUBSTRING(name, -4),
name =   SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name)-4)
```

and for trim

```
update mytable
set year = SUBSTRING(name, -4),
name =   trim(SUBSTRING(name, 1, LENGTH(name)-4) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
UPDATE table SET `Name` = REPLACE(`Name`, SUBSTRING(`Name`,-4), '') , `Year` = SUBSTRING(`Name`,-4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup first for security reason then do:

```
UPDATE
yourtable SET
`Year` = substr(`Name`,-4),
`Name` = substring_index(`Name`,substr(`Name`,-5),1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: last substr(`Name`,-5) is -5 because of the blank space between text and date, if your data is structured as your image suggests.